# JQuery dropping click events

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm currently experiencing click events intermittently not firing. Anyone else ever had this problem?

Code is simple:

```
<ul class="iconButtons ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Save">
    <span class="btnSave ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btnSave").click(function() {
       alert("Sometimes I never get called!");
    });
});
```

Occurs frequently in all browsers. Using `live` demonstrates the same behaviour.

Comment: are you binding the event (click) on domready ($(document).ready())?

Comment: @alinn `click()` events don't need to be put in the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: @JamWaffles - They do, or they need to be included within `<script>` tags after the elements to which they bind within the DOM.

Comment: @JamWaffles doesn't the selector $(".class") work only after the element is loaded?

Comment: @alinn - Yes, sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: @alinn: As long as the script is further down in the document than the element, it's fine. The problem only comes when you put the script *above* the element (say, in the `head` tag).

Comment: A live example would be very helpful. Try replicating the behavior on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Did you try using Firebug? The new version of firebug show the jQuery bindings in the HTML tab inline so you can know when the binding is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the span which the click event was being added to only occupied the central part of the button's graphic. Clicking directly on the glyph always fired the event, but clicking slightly outside (although seemingly still inside the button) would not raise the event.

I hope this helps anyone else using mini JQuery buttons in the same way they are presented on the [JQuery UI ThemeRoller page](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Answer (score 2):

I would venture to say that there is some other complication going on to prevent what you are doing.

Here are some possibilities:

1. Unless you give that empty span `display:block;` then on some browsers it will have a width and height of 0px and be unclickable. Keep in mind just adding width and height to a span won't actually work on `inline` elements.
2. You are ajax'ing content in, and not rebinding the click handler. You can check at any time by doing `$(".btnSave").data("events")` in your firebug or chrome console to see the number of events to that element.
3. Another event is usurping your event, using the technique in #2 may help reveal this.
4. Your click handle *is* being called, but not returning the right result causing to believe it wasn't being called. Have you tried adding an `alert('called')` to the very top of the click handler?
5. Are you certain the element exists in the DOM prior to appending the click element to it? You can check by doing an `alert($(".btnSave").length)` at the line JUST before you bind the click handler.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use an anchor  instead of a span for your button it will fire for sure.
Put

```
$(".btnSave").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("Clicked");
});
```

In IE, you also have to have content inside an anchor for it to work: background image / background color/ text (maybe also with big negative text-indent)

Comment: `span` elements fire clicks just fine, there's no need to make it an anchor to resolve this problem. (There can be reasons related to accessibility software, but that's a different thing.)

Comment: Turns out the span which the click event was being added to only occupied the central part of the button's graphic. Clicking directly on the glyph always fired the event, but clicking slightly outside (although seemingly still inside the button) would not raise the event. Thanks for hinting that it could be a DOM issue rather than JS :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code will hook up event handlers to all elements with that class *that already exist when the code is called*. If you add more later, they won't get the handler because, well, you haven't asked that they do. :-) Options:

- You could use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead, if you add and remove these elements dynamically. `live` (and the related [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)) use *event delegation* to watch for events rather than actually attaching the handlers to the elements in question. `live` uses the `document` itself. Since `click` bubbles, `document` sees all clicks (that aren't cancelled), and so jQuery's document-wide handler can see if the click was on a `.btnSave` element and fire your handler if so.
- You could put your script at the bottom of the page (just before the closing `</body>` element), so that all of the elements are there when you hook up your handler.
- You could use jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to ensure the DOM is ready before you hook up your handlers.

Alternately, as quoted your `span` is pretty darned hard to click on (what with being completely empty) unless there's some CSS giving it dimensions you haven't shown... ;-)

---

**Update**: You've said the span has dimensions, and that the handler is being hooked up fine (you didn't say **how** you know that). The only thing left is if something is hooking the `click` event on those elements and cancelling them (e.g., via [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/), [like this](http://jsbin.com/uwuhub)), and it happens that they're earlier in the event handler list than your handler is. It seems more likely that there's an issue hooking things up, though.

Comment: Event is registering fine, as sometimes the click event is fired. CSS is giving it dimensions - it's taken directly from the JQuery UI Themes page (scroll down to see the little square buttons).

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield: How do you know the event handler is being registered fine? If it's not firing, I'd look pretty hard at that. If that's not it, I've added another possibility, but I still suspect event registration. jQuery does *not* just "drop" click events.

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield: My original update may not have been sufficiently clear, I've updated it again.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many different reasons for that, eg.:

- the JS code you are referring to is **not executed correctly** (does not bind the event in the correct moment in time), try executing it when the DOM is ready:

  ```
  jQuery(function(){
      // your code goes here
  });
  ```
- you may be **creating this element dynamically** (if you bind it first, then create element, then this element will not have the specific event). The solution is to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) jQuery functions.
- the **event may be unbound somewhere** in your code. Try searching for usage of [`.unbind()` jQuery's function](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) within JS code (or even HTML).

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield: As I said, there may be many problems resulting in this. If binding events by `.live()` does not help, you may be placing the code in the wrong place (try executing it on DOM ready) or some other code may be unbinding this (try searching for `.unbind()` or similar) - all of this has been mentioned in my answer, though.

Comment: Using `.live()` shouldn't really be a cop-out solution. It should really only be used if the element is intentionally being added after the click handler by design, such as in an AJAX result. If a click handler isn't working, one should figure out *why* it's not working, and not just grasp at straws to `.live()`. Even if `.live()` worked, unless you know why it solved the problem, you're sure to make it again.

Comment: @Nucleon: I bet you did not read my answer, because I mentioned when `.live()` and `.delegate()` could solve the issue. It could solve the problem if the element is **created dynamically**, whether " _by design_ ", " _by mistake_ " or by anything else. Plus I think `.delegate()` is better than `.live()` (because of the syntax, not how it works).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running jquery-ui-1.10.3 and I'm having the same intermittent issue with .toggle buttons -- they just aren't very responsive. I think it's inherent in jquery-ui because even on their demo page the toggle button feels less-than-awesome in terms of tactile response. If I click very slowly and deliberately I can *usually* get the button to toggle on and off but fast clicking is very hit or miss. I've tried all the tips to speed up jquery-ui but none have worked.